# Coditional statement in Arm template for msDeploy packageuri

Tags: json, azure, azure-functions, azure-rm-template

My goal is to deploy a packaged .zip with msDeploy and another if a condition is met. currently the template looks like this:

```
"resources": [
    {
      "name": "MSDeploy",
      "type": "Extensions",
      "apiVersion": "2015-02-01",
      "dependsOn": [
        "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/Sites', variables('functionAppName'))]"
      ],
      "properties": {
        "addOnPackages": [
        {
           "packageUri": "[parameters('zipUri')]"
        },

        {
           "packageUri": "[if(parameters('boolparam'), parameters('zipUri2'), '')]"
        }
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
```

This works if boolparam is true, but fails if it is false. Is it possible to always deploy zipUri, and zipUri2 with condition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try doing this:

```
"variables": {
    "package1": [
        {
            "packageUri": "[parameters('zipUri')]"
        }
    ]
    "package2": [
        {
            "packageUri": "[parameters('zipUri2')]"
        }
    ]
}
```

and then in your msdeploy definition:

```
"properties": {
    "addOnPackages": "[if(parameters('boolparam'), concat(variables('package1'), variables('pakcage2')), variables('package1'))]"
```

Comment: Works perfect! Thanks